# How to convert InDesign IDML to Tiff?

Tags: automation, tiff, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I have a requirement to take idml files provided by a client, twiddle them a bit to fill in some placeholders and generate a TIFF file. This needs to happen automatically and I have InDesign Server at my disposal.

I have the first part down. I have also found how to connect to InDesign Server via SOAP and convert IDML files to hi-res PDF or low-res JPG ([This implies a few other other options](http://indesignscriptingreference.com/cs3/javascript-cs3/exportformat-enum.htm)).

I am at a bit of a loss as to how to take it the rest of the way to generate a TIFF file, [the adobe forums have not been much help](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4324592). It is my impression that this sort of thing is exactly why the IDML format was introduced so I'm assuming there's decent support out there for it but the best I've been able to come up with so far is to go `IDML via Indesign Server to PDF (or SVG) via Inkscape Command-line to PNG via System.Drawing to TIFF` but that seems horribly contrived and fault-prone (and I have no idea how I'm going to handle multiple pages).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to export to TIFF via InDesign Server, however I did find [this post on the Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/987386?start=0&tstart=0) that suggests using Photoshop to render the Tiff after exporting it as a PDF from IDS. Maybe that would be an option? Otherwise maybe you could use one of the formats that you CAN export from (i.e. JPG, PDF, EPS).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree. You'd think there would be export options for TIFF formats. Then this would be extremely easy with scripting. Or at least a way to convert another format to TIFF. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, [I ended up using Ghostscript](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ghostscript) to achieve the results.